# Communication between 2 ListBoxes in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, publish-subscribe

I want to build a WPF backend app for a shop. And one view should contain 2 listboxes. 1 for the items which one can buy and 1 for the categories.

I want to grey out items based on selection. Now more details:

So far my view model has an `ObservableCollection<ShopItem>`
and the class `ShopItem` has a `price`, `title` and a `list of Categories`

I want to bind `ShopItems` to 1 `ListBox` and the Distinct `Category` to another 2nd `ListBox`
Since a `ShopItem` can have multiple Categories I want to gray out all other `categories` beside the one that belong to the Selected `ShopItem`. So selection in my first `listbox` should control appereance in my 2nd `listbox`.

On the other hand side, when I select a `category` I would like to gray out all other `ShopItems` beside the ones that belong to that `category`. So again `listbox` 2 should also affect appereance in `listbox` 1.

With "grayed out" I mean the items should have another style.

I saw something about MultiTrigger that can swap out Template Styling based on conditions.
I am not sure if I can just bind my `ObservableCollection<ShopItem>` or would need to have two lists here. Do I need some pub/sub between the two lists. I would like to avoid to foreach over all elements in viewmodel each selection changes, any thoughts here? 
I'm scratching my head how to solve this right now. Any suggestions would be great...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can get away with iterating over a collection as to change the list to grey out then each item in the list must notify of the change. The following is an example of how you could do it. Where there is `IsSelected` you can define a `ValueConverter` to change the font colour.

```
class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //displayed on the first list
    public ObservableCollection<ShopItemViewModel> Shops { get; private set; }

    //displayed on the second list
    public ObservableCollection<CategoryViewModel> AllCategories { get; private set; }

    //when the user clicks an item on the first list
    private ShopItemViewModel _selectedShop;
    public ShopItemViewModel SelectedShop
    {
        get { return _selectedShop; }
        set
        {
            _selectedShop = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedShop");
            foreach (CategoryViewModel cat in AllCategories)
                cat.Refresh();
        }
    }

    //when the user clicks an item on the second list
    private CategoryViewModel _selectedCat;
    public CategoryViewModel SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return _selectedCat; }
        set
        {
            _selectedCat = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
            foreach (ShopItemViewModel shops in Shops)
                shops.Refresh();
        }
    }
}

class ShopItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; private set; }

    public ShopItemViewModel(ViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
    }
    private ViewModel _vm;

    public void Refresh()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            if (_vm.SelectedCategory != null)
            {
                return Categories.Contains(_vm.SelectedCategory);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}

class CategoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public CategoryViewModel(ViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
    }
    private ViewModel _vm;

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            if (_vm.SelectedShop != null)
            {
                return _vm.SelectedShop.Categories.Contains(this);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```